# Running two versions of Java in cmd

Tags: java, windows, javac

I have configured my JAVA_HOME to point to java 8, but require the use of Java 7 for a different application. Is there a way of easily switching between the two?

I have tried to define another environment variable called

```
JAVA7 C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
```

but I am not sure running:

```
%JAVA7% program.jar
```

is the correct method, as I keep getting the error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Place double quotes around the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that space you have between "Program" and "Files"? It makes problems. Use:

```
JAVA7 C:\"Program Files"\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
         ↑             ↑
```

Or:

```
"%JAVA7%"
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

We can point only one version of java in JAVA_HOME

so create a batch file with

```
set JAVA_HOME="path-to-java-home"
set path="path-to-java-home\bin"
<your-application>.exe or <your-application>.sh
```

above lines are used to overwrite existing system environment JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: Thanks, would I need to set the path and java home back again afterwards?

Comment: not required. it will applicable only the application which you have mentioned(<your-application>.exe)

Answer (score 1):

use double quotes as below:

```
"%JAVA7%" program.jar
```